# PHP: simple file uploader on web-site

Tags: php, file-upload

I need a simple PHP file uploader to upload files on my web-site. It would be nice with a progress bar.If there are no simple uploaders I am wiling to use others too!

Please suggest a script, product (free).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/ in some of my past projects.

UPDATE: since the link to the latest version is broken, I would like to suggest another good plugin to upload files:

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, I used a previous release, not the latest. I've update my answer with a new plugin still based on jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend this File Uploader module from the Dojox javascript framework/toolkit. It is not a simple uploader but it is extensively well documented, plus it is AJAX/driven and also uses flash:

[dojox.form.FileUploader](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/form/FileUploader.html)

You might feel hesitant if it happens to be the very first time you use file uploaders, but let me tell you this: I wish I had known of javascript frameworks and toolkits from the very beginning of my web development career, even if only for the sake of better understanding the potential of what's already out there.

Have a look at it, it is free, well documented, with many live examples, and it works great.